# Python efficiently getting a specific value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I am using an API to get results from a database that is returned in JSON format. I'm then trying to just extract certain keys/values and append them to a blank list. The field I want is eissn and the API returns results like this:

```
[
{'type': 'doi', 'id': '10.16472/j.chinatobacco.2017.045'}, 
{'type': 'pissn', 'id': '1004-5708'}, 
{'type': 'eissn', 'id': '1004-5708'}
]
```

I want to extract the eissn id which i have tried using this code:

```
deissnlist = []
for i in range(0,lengthD):
    deissnlist.append(doajresult[i]['bibjson']['identifier'][3] 
    ['id'])
```

Where lengthD/i are the number of results returned from the API. The problem is that the eissn ID is not always the 3rd dictionary in the list. Is there any way I can search the tuples and only get the eissn ID without using another for loop (and thus going from O(n) to O(n^2)? The expected output is just the single value of the eissn id (in this case 1004-5708)

I tried converting the list to a dictionary but that didn't work because it treated each tuple as it's own dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: There are no tuples here, your code is not runnable and you didn't show us the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood question and over simplified; but, if you are looking to simply extract a list of the ids from that sample input, this is how I would do it:

```
input = [
    {'type': 'doi', 'id': '10.16472/j.chinatobacco.2017.045'},
    {'type': 'pissn', 'id': '1004-5708'},
    {'type': 'eissn', 'id': '1004-5708'}
]

result = [x.get('id') for x in input]

print(result)

['10.16472/j.chinatobacco.2017.045', '1004-5708', '1004-5708']
```

Or for just the ids where type is eissn:

```
result = [x.get('id') for x in input if x.get('type') == 'eissn']
```

Comment: This is good, but I only want the 3rd ID (where type = 'eissn')

Comment: Awesome.  Dict comprehension is the cat's meow.  For complicated ones I still write loop then refactor, but my brain is starting to think in compressed syntax.

Comment: I do pretty well with a lot of programming concepts but dict comprehension has always been difficult for me.

Comment: I thought this page was really helpful without being too wordy. Breaks it down into basic pseudo-syntax which I always like (i.e. [expression for item in list if condition]): [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much! Wish i could upvote you more than once.